How to show just only one of the headers in the REST API request with Pino logger?
We use Pino as logger for our REST API. We have set the pino options to redact the headers for req and res with
redact: ["req.headers", "res.headers"],
as we do not want to show all the headers in the logs. But there is one header which contains a transaction id value which I want to include in the logs.
In another question I found how to remove one header from the request.headers, but in this case I just want to see one of the headers, as well as other fields of the request as id, method, url, remoteAddress, remotePort.
I'm thinking I could override the serializer with
serializers: {
        req: (req) => {req.id, req.method, req.headers["transaction"], req.remoteAddress, req.remotePort},
        // Do not include extensive error message in log output
        err: (err) => err.message

But seems a bit of overkill having to redefine the whole request to just include 1 header.
Are there other ways to show just one of the headers, and all other values in the request?

A better option than the described in the question (which actually did not work) is to use
    serializers: {
        req(req) {
            Object.assign(req, { "transaction-id": req.headers["transaction-id"] });
            return req;
        },
        err: (err) => err.message
    }

this adds a new field to the request if the header is present. The other headers in the request are still redacted, and the expected value is presented in the log output together with all the other values in the request which are presented by Pino.
